# Apply bold italic character style to tag when importing xml to adobe indesign

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

Is it possible to apply a bold italic character style to a tag in adobe indesign.
Currently you can create a character style e.g. 'strong' and map this style to a tag, so when you import an xml, the 'strong' character style will apply to any 'strong' tags.

However, if you were to create a new character style e.g. bold italic, how could you apply it to a tag? At the moment, if you were to import the following

```
<strong><em>I like cake!</em></strong>
```

and you had character styles defined for strong and em, only the em character style will be applied as the xml tree node looks like:

[image]

Is it possible to apply a bold italic character style to `<strong><em>` so it doesnt come out in just italics?

Comment: This is a similar letdown as to *exporting*. Try a simple XSLT that transforms (properly nested) pairs into a single XML code. You probably need to work out what should happen with `<em>wot <strong>now</strong>?</em>` nodes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will give you an "emstrong" tag for em nested inside strong or vice versa.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>        
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="em[../../strong]|strong[../../em]">
        <xsl:element name="emstrong">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```